# How to use Parse IOS SDK with REST Push Notifications from Rails Back-end

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, rest, parse-platform, push-notification

I am new to Rails and Parse, currently trying to use Parse Push REST API with an IOS app that has a Rails Back-end.

[image]

The Installations are created through REST API calls from the back-end to Parse.

With that pattern is it possible to use the IOS SDK Client methods of PFInstallation ? such as

```
if (application.applicationIconBadgeNumber != 0) {
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    [[PFInstallation currentInstallation] saveInBackground];
}
```

Or in the case of Push Notifications from REST API, the Parse IOS SDK cannot be used? Do PFInstallations also need to be linked to a PFUser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you're trying to accomplish.

If you're using Parse only to send Push Notification, you shouldn't it too much trouble. You should use either direct notification system (iOS/Android) or `Urban Airship` type of tool.

If you have a better reason to user Parse then you should first read https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#push-notifications.

You could manually create installation using the Parse REST API (using the already collected iOS Push Token for exemple, don't know Android, sorry) or if you're using Rails you could use the gem: parse-ruby-client (https://github.com/adelevie/parse-ruby-client#installations).

Then you can use the Parse REST API (https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#push-notifications-sending-pushes).

Hope it answer your question.