# Parse Push Notifications with custom backend

Tags: ios, rest, parse-platform, push-notification

I would like to use Push Notifications with a custom existing back-end from an IOS App.

I'm quite new to Parse and can't figure out if I need to set a double authentication system in order to create PFUsers along with PFInstallations.

Push notifications will be sent through the REST Api

1. Device Token -> Existing Back-End (Store Token) -> (Parse Rest API) -> Create PFInstallation (and PFUser?)

I understand that simply creating the PFInstallation through REST API allows to:
- send and receive push notifications
- target push with channels

But what about the badge count? When simply creating the PFInstallations, the badge count can be tracked :

- in my custom back-end (but that duplicates the PFInstallation, in Parse and in my back-end)
- retrieved through REST : IOS -> stored token in back-end -> (Parse Rest API) -> Get the PFInstallation -> back-end -> IOS (which looks a bit complicated)

Can someone using Push Notifications from a custom back-end give some insights about the best way to keep client synced with PFInstallation?
Thx for your help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Parse IOS SDK with REST Push Notifications from Rails Back-end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29252152/how-to-use-parse-ios-sdk-with-rest-push-notifications-from-rails-back-end)